# My Public IP address

Tags: networking, ip

So I found out I can easily get my Public IP address from my work. I can ping it i can even log in to my router from work. How do i defend myself from this? what are ways someone can get into my home network? Can someone explain this a bit for me?

Comment: Most routers have a "Only allow connections from the intranet" setting which will prevent external logins and exploits. Several have a firewall setting that can be used to prevent *any* external connection unless it's in response from intranet activity, so that your line appears "dead" to any casual onlooker. **At the very least**, I expect you set a hard-to-guess admin password on the device.

Comment: IP Address: That thing you must be assigned in order to use the internet so you can get the packets back.

Comment: You can switch off ping response. Routers by default have all ports closed to external packets. Unless you opened it with port forwarding you're ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I found out I can easily get my Public IP address from my work. I
>   can ping it i can even log in to my router from work. How do i defend
>   myself from this?

First of all, you should check to make sure your home router only accepts connections over HTTPS and **not HTTP**. Usually you can find such a setting in your routers "Administration" section, but it really depends on the manufacturer and model to the exact location of that option.

Second, your router may support disabling login over wireless and the WAN interface. Again this depends on individual routers so you will have to check if yours supports this feature. Worst comes to worst, disable HTTP/HTTPS access through the firewall on the WAN interface.

You may also want to look into configuring your routers firewall to drop connections after X amount of failed tries. This could be done from the GUI or if you use [something like dd-wrt](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Preventing_Brute_Force_Attacks) you can use iptables. Note that as the link mentioned dd-wrt by default has rules for this in most images since 2011.

> What are ways someone can get into my home network?

I'm going to answer this a little differently by just listing things you can do to harden the system and why those help:

- They can attack the default ports for common services like ssh, telnet, http, etc. If they are lucky they will be able to use an exploit or brute force using common credentials. This is why it's important to always change the ports services like ssh run on and to have firewall rules that drop a connection after X failed attempts.
- **Disable any services you do not use.** The less you have running on the router, the harder it is to get owned. Also be sure to **disable login access from services like telnet and plain HTTP** as they do not use any form of encryption and your credentials are sent in plaintext. If an attacker was to sniff the connection outside your WAN and you logged in from work they could see your username and password as well as what you were doing on the router.
- **Its also important to patch/update your router regularly!** If you use dd-wrt you should update frequently to ensure you are not leaving yourself exposed. So many people forget to do this and it doesn't help that device manufacturers will release all these devices but then never provide updates for them. If you don't do this, attackers could use well known exploits to gain access into your router.
- This is perhaps a little overkill for a home network but you can also scan your router every now and then using [openvas](http://www.openvas.org/) to see what issues are present. This can help you be proactive and prevent attackers from exploiting vulnerabilities against your router.

Comment: Thank you very much, Im still in learning phase with this and i kinda panicked when I saw my IP address so easily accessible with skype resolver.